# how to append object value using inside object

Tags: javascript

```
const result = {
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "items": [
            { name: 'shark', likes: 'ocean', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'turtle', likes: 'pond', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'otter', likes: 'fish biscuits', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } }
        ]
   }
}

const response = result.response.items.map( record => {
    return {...record, {result.response.items.address: {success: 1 }}
})
console.log(response);
```

How to add one extra success key with value 1 inside address object tried this ways doesn't get success please guide thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Objects require key-value pairs, but `result.items.address:` is not a valid key name

Comment: why -4 just wondering ??

Comment: can any one give answer of -4 vote??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```js
const result = {
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "items": [
            { name: 'shark', likes: 'ocean', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'turtle', likes: 'pond', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'otter', likes: 'fish biscuits', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } }
        ]
   }
}

var newitems = result.response.items.map( record => {
    var val = record;
    val.address.success = 1;
    return val;
});
var response = result;
response.response.items = newitems;
console.log(response);
```

Comment: want to append on more value success: 1 not to remove others as well

Comment: where is area and zone it should be there

Comment: Edited it for you @Shivam.

Comment: Yeah got to know after that thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, simple way to bind the key `success`

```js
const result = {
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "items": [
            { name: 'shark', likes: 'ocean', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'turtle', likes: 'pond', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } },
            { name: 'otter', likes: 'fish biscuits', address: { area: 'south', zone: 'danger' } }
        ]
    }
}


result['response']['items'].forEach(rs => {
    rs['address']['success'] = 1
});

console.log(result)
```